# How to calculate the elapsed time of a flag status per day?

Tags: time-series, bigdata

I'd like to figure out the **elapsed time** between flag status changes.

Simplified **example**: a person can only be sad or happy. I'd like to know how long each mood was active until it changed.

I'm using common storage and a script to loop the records, which is very expensive. I'm **looking for a general best practice**. I'm open to use any technology in combination or as a replacement. I'm new to data science and probably miss the right terms. Related advices are very appreciated.

**Index: user_mood_log**

```
 |    changed_at    |  mood  | user |
 ------------------------------
 | yyyy-mm-dd 12:00 | sad    | John |
 | yyyy-mm-dd 15:00 | happy  | John |
 | yyyy-mm-dd 18:00 | happy  | John |
 |        ...       |   ...  |  ... |
```

**Index: user_mood_log_daily**

```
 |    date    |  sad  | happy | user |
 -------------------------------------
 | 2019-05-22 |   3   |   21  | John |
 | 2019-05-21 |   5   |   19  | John |
 |    ...     |  ...  |   ... |  ... |
```

**Challenges:**

1. The last record of *yesterday* (or even older) needs to be considered. Means I can't simply group by day.
2. A mood might not change for several days.
3. Duplicated mood logs are possible.

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your definition of "common storage"?  Exactly how is the data stored; database, text files, formatted text, binary files?

Comment: @Edmund I kept it "common" to not influence the answerer, as I'm willing to migrate to another storage. Currently I'm using Elasticsearch.

Comment: ElasticSearch is a search engine.  What is the data store behind it in your implementation?

Comment: @Edmund These records are currently only stored in ElasticSearch.

Comment: ElasticSearch serializes data as JSON.

Comment: What if you just pass data to a if condition, if mood is same as previously then sum to total mood, else just flag a change (and show total previous mood hours). 
For data, i think you can use streaming.

Comment: how „big“ is your dataset, I‘m asking, because if you can load the dataset into R or Python, the thing might be relatively easy.

Comment: @Peter it's what I'm doing at the moment. It's too much data (for my setup) to run it in realtime and is currently a background task. I was hoping about a technology/storage with a feature like that which allows me to use it's cache. Elasticsearch allows scripts but it's not enough.

Answer (score 2):

Python's [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) package has the capability to answer all those questions, assuming the data can fit into the computer's memory.

Pandas can process [timeseries](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) data, find [time deltas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html), and remove [duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html).

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an example by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

You may apply [Wolfram Language](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/) to your project. There is a free [Wolfram Engine](https://www.wolfram.com/developer/) for developers that plugs into many IDEs. It also has the [Wolfram Client Library for Python](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/) to use these functions in Python.

I presume that there is a API to get the data as JSON or CSV or a stream of these or some other format.  Depending on the API you can use functions from either the [HTTP Requests & Responses](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/HTTPRequestsAndResponses.html) guide or the [Web Operations](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WebOperations.html) guide.

Since no data is provide I'll start by generating timed mood runs.  To ensure there are runs I will use a [`DiscreteMarkovProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteMarkovProcess.html) with a transition matrix that slightly favours the current state over moving to another state.

```
MatrixForm[tm = {{0.6, 0.4}, {0.4, 0.6}}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

[`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph.html) can take a `DiscreteMarkovProcess` so this can be visualised as

```
mood = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, tm];
Graph@mood
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

or with a bit of formatting for clarity.

```
Graph[
 Flatten@MapIndexed[Labeled[DirectedEdge @@ #2, #1] &, tm, {2}],
 VertexSize -> Medium,
 VertexStyle -> LightGreen,
 VertexLabels -> Thread[Range[2] -> Map[Placed[#, Center] &, {"Happy", "Sad"}]]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

[`RandomFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomFunction.html) will simulate this process and I will convert the integer values to text with [`ReplaceAll (/.)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) in order to have the same data types as in your ElasticSearch. [`DateRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateRange.html) will be use to create the timestamps 2 hours apart as in your example.

```
SeedRandom[987]
n = 20;
data = Transpose@
   {
    With[{start = DateObject@{2019, 1, 1, 0}},
     DateRange[start, DatePlus[start, {2 n, "Hour"}], Quantity[2, "Hour"]]
     ],
    RandomFunction[mood, {0, n}]["Values"] /. Thread[Range@2 -> {"Happy", "Sad"}]
    };
```

This gives the following Happy-Sad sequence viewed below with [`DateListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot.html).

```
DateListPlot[KeySort@GroupBy[Last]@data /. Thread[{"Happy", "Sad"} -> Range@2],
 Joined -> False]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Now that there is data the actual work can begin. The first 2 items are

```
data[[;; 2]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

`data` can be [`SplitBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplitBy.html) the [`Last`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Last.html) value in each item.  These runs can be [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html)d so there is one row of [`DateObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html)s and one of the string values. [`Apply (@@@)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)ing [`MinMax`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinMax.html) to the dates and [`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html) to the values (as they are all the same for each run) gets the start and end points of each run.

```
runs = {MinMax@#1, First@#2} & @@@ Transpose /@ SplitBy[data, Last]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

I have decided that a run begins immediately after its prior run ends and ends on its last data point.  Therefore, I need to include the previous run's end point to calculate the run time of the run.  By [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html)ing the list in pairs ([`FoldPairList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPairList.html)) the [`DateDifference`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateDifference.html) in `"Hour"` between the end of the previous and current can be calculated.

```
runTimes =
 FoldPairList[
  {
    {DateDifference[##, "Hour"] & @@ MinMax@Rest@Flatten@{##}[[All, 1]], Last@#2},
    #2
   } &,
  First@runs,
  runs
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

`DateDifference` returns a [`Quantity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html) object of the time unit requested.

```
runTimes[[1, 1]] // InputForm
```

> ```
> Quantity[8, "Hours"]
> ```

Quantity objects are known throughout the language so from here further processing or analysis can continue. For example [`BarChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart.html) visualisations like

```
BarChart[Labeled @@@ runTimes, ChartLabels -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that the abbreviation for hours was [`Automatic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Automatic.html)ally placed as an [`AxesLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesLabel.html).

Hope this helps.